# Is ControlsOverload site a sister site of SO/SU/Meta etc?

Tags: discussion, sister-site, data-explorer

Is the site [Controlsoverload](http://controlsoverload.com/) part of the StackOverflow / SuperUser / Meta / etc group?

It looks the same, and has a link to stackexchange at the bottom. It also says it is in Beta, but I don't see it listed in Area51.

I don't seem to be able to associate my ID with it either like I have been able to with SO/SU.

So, just wondering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a Stack Exchange 1.0 site, which means that it is from the original release of Stack Exchange. That version was a commercial product but is no longer supported, so you cannot link your accounts.